# How to link theme fonts directory in WordPress CSS?

Tags: css

So I installed WordPress locally and I'm on theme-development. I'm having a problem in linking my font files in my CSS. Is there any alternatives or best practices on how to link font files in a theme folder in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your theme's folder structure is similar to the following:

```
my-theme
 |- index.php
 |- style.css
 |- fonts/font-name.ttf
 |- inc/some-file.php
```

then the code to connect the font files in your `style.css` will be:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Name';
  src: url('fonts/font-name.ttf');
}

body{
   font-family: 'Font Name', sans-serif;
}
```

There shouldn't be any problem!